# Hide list from SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Say I have a list on a site which contains a few lookups. Now my users like to use the SharePoint app (The one provided by microsoft and downloadable in Play Store and Apple Store), however with no support for lookup columns in the app they are able to create items without the (mandatory) information being populated.

Is it possible to hide the list from the SharePoint app (not the browser)? I'd rather have the users not being able to create/see items via the app than having them creating incomplete items.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you defined a custom list in your app(add-in), you could hide the list from UI by below setting.

[image]

Comment: It is not my app/add-in - it's the Microsoft SharePoint app (search Play store or Apple store). Also I most definetely do not want to hide the list from the browser - I want to hide it from the app :)

Comment: I think the question wasn't clear

Comment: I think you need provide feedback for Mobile app in proper user voice forum. https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/540331-sharepoint-mobile-app-for-android or https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/350433-sharepoint-mobile-app-for-ios

Comment: So as I suspected it is not possible to prevent users from editing a list in the incomplete SharePoint app provided by Microsoft. Not hugely surpricing but very annoying none the less.